# Add column as a foreign key on autogenerated entity

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, abp

I'm following the current [documentation](https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/c81732c1cf91c49cfc1d0fcc58b6746d9ded69f5/docs/en/Community-Articles/2022-07-19-How-To-Add-Custom-Property-To-The-User-Entity/How-To-Add-Custom-Property-To-The-User-Entity.md) about how to update the autogenerated user entity on abp framework and add a new column.

The difference is that I want to bind to another table, so the new column should be a foreign key. I added the table class, but in the mapping, I can not add a foreign key.

I try to use `HasOne` but it does not let me use it:

```
ObjectExtensionManager.Instance
                .MapEfCoreProperty<IdentityUser, Guid>(
                    UserConsts.PropertyName,
                    (_, propertyBuilder) =>
                    {
                        propertyBuilder.HasOne<MyModel>().WithOne().HasForeignKey(x => x.MyPropertyId).IsRequired().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
                    }
                );
```

Error message:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error CS1061  'PropertyBuilder' does not contain a definition for
> 'HasOne' and no accessible extension method 'HasOne' accepting a first
> argument of type 'PropertyBuilder' could be found (are you missing a
> using directive or an assembly reference?)

Do you know how I can import the property correctly?

The `MapEFCoreProperty` method:

```
public static ObjectExtensionManager MapEfCoreProperty<TEntity, TProperty>(
        [NotNull] this ObjectExtensionManager objectExtensionManager,
        [NotNull] string propertyName)
        where TEntity : IHasExtraProperties, IEntity
    {
        return objectExtensionManager.MapEfCoreProperty(
            typeof(TEntity),
            typeof(TProperty),
            propertyName
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HasOne` is a method defined in the `EntityTypeBuilder` class.  Therefore it is not possible to use it on a `PropertyBuilder` instance. To map to a different table, you need to use `HasOne` on the `EntityTypeBuilder` instance.